# svg, javascript:отрисовка с маской

Tags: javascript, css, svg, background

У меня есть коэффициент `rating`, требуется отрисовать звёздочки (изображения заданы в виде svg), которые визуализируют этот коэффициент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**svg:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="260" height="245">
    <path d="m55,237 74-228 74,228L9,96h240"/>
</svg>
```

Я реализовал это в лоб с помощью 5 блоков `div` и 3 svg задних фонов (пустой, половинчатый, полный)

```
<div class = 'rating'>
    <div class = 'on'></div>
    <div class = 'on'></div>
    <div class = 'half'></div>
    <div class = 'off'></div>
    <div class = 'off'></div>
</div>
```

Html код естественно генерировался через javascript в зависимости от значения `rating`

Но мне очень не нравится эта "влобность", некрасивое и неоптимальное решение (да и выглядит жутко).

**Подскажите, как это можно сделать с помощью одного только svg (ну и небольшой доли javascript)?**

Как я понимаю,

1. потребуется одна звездочка,
2. которая будет размножена в группу из 5
   звездочек
3. цвет у этой группы будет "серый"
4. ещё одна группа цвета "золотой" будет наложена сверху на серую группу
5. ширина группы "золотой" будет вычисляться `rating / 5`

**P.S.**

А если таких картинок понадобится 1000, браузер не просядет (картинки маленькие, это тут показаны большие для удобства)?

**P.P.S.**

Или не извращаться и реализовать всё это через 2 div с обычным png фоном из 5 звездочек (золотых и серых), просто ширина "золотого" блока будет задаваться?

**P.P.P.S.**

Вообще что наука :) говорит по поводу использования на сайтах svg в виде разных картинок и иконок (особенно, когда таких картинок/иконок много на сайте)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно немного схитрить использовать 2 блока с звездочками

```css
.rate {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}
.rate .blank {
  color: #aaa;
  position: absolute;
}
.rate .rated {
  color: #ffdd00;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate">
  <div class="blank">☆☆☆☆☆</div>
  <div class="rated">★★★★★</div>
</div>
```

Или псевдоэлементы

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.rate {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: flex;
}
.rate .stars {
  color: #aaa;
  position: relative;
}
.rate .stars::before {
  content: "★★★★★";
  position: absolute;
  width: 53%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFDD00;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate">
  <div class="stars">☆☆☆☆☆</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А это хорошая идея

Comment: на счёт псевдоэлемента - до него надо с помощью JS достучаться, чтобы динамически поменять ширину, иначе не вариант/

А вот использование символа "звездочка" - это блин круто!!! (не знал, что он есть) (правда опять - надо UTF врубать)